# Thermostat needs to be set very high to work

Tags: air-conditioning, thermostat

Our home thermostat is behaving strangely.
Let say it shows that the current room temperature is 60F.
If we set it to 63F it will start the Fan (ventilation) but will not actually start the heating so it just blows (cold) air.
To make it warm the place, we need to set it way above current temperature, let's say in that scenario we need to set it to 70F. But when it approaches 70F it stops the heating but keeps the blower on. so it get's stock below it's target and never reaches it. 
Same things happens when it goes down. If we set it to 60F but the room temperature is 65F as the room temperature goes down, when it get's to 60F it starts the blower but does not engage the heater part.
**Question is:** is this a thermostat problem or the problem is in the heating unit?  Any solution other than replacing the the thermostat? 
The thermostat is branded as "White/rodgers" and the unit is one of those electric air conditioning units (that both can be used to warm or cool the house).

Comment: Is it a multi-stage thermostat? If the thermostat is designed for a multi-stage furnace, it may be miswired to the fan, the first stage of the furnace may not be working correctly, or you may be mistaking the first stage for only blowing cold air.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch . I didn't know that there are such things, I need to look into it. Will post if I found out.